# CSS outline around a flex element not including child element margin?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using an outline and a margin in an attempt to avoid a double border around some flex-elements.

If I apply a margin to the flex element itself it works as expected. However, if I apply the margin to a child element the double border shows up again.

Why does the outline correctly render only when the margin is applied to the parent flex element? Is this a bug?

```css
.comment {
   padding:20px;
}

#flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-element {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  outline: 5px solid #ccc;
}



.flex-element-working {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.flex-content-working {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: 5px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class='comment'>
  Why doesn't this work?:
</div>


<div id='flex-container'>
  <div class='flex-element'>
    <div class='flex-content'>
      <div class='comment'> Flex Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='flex-element'>
    <div class='flex-content'>
     <div class='comment'> Flex Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='comment'>
  Working Example:
</div>

<div id='flex-container'>
  <div class='flex-element-working'>
    <div class='flex-content-working'>
     <div class='comment'> Flex Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='flex-element-working'>
    <div class='flex-content-working'>
      <div class='comment'> Flex Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, you can inspect and see the `width`s - I guess its obvious!

Answer (score 0):

The point is in the top flex container (bad working) in double outline the left on is for the right div and the right one is for left div! Please add this style to your code:

```
.flex-content{background-color:red;}
```

You will see the out line is how you want.

.flex-content divs have width 303px But .flex-content-working divs have width 298px so in second one we have not such problem.

To see the width of your elements use developer tools of your browser and layout or box menu.

Answer (score 0):

A bit another approach using `padding` and `box-shadow`:

```css
#flex-container {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px;
}
.flex-element {
  flex-grow: 1;
  box-shadow: inherit;
}
.comment {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='flex-container'>
  <div class='flex-element'>
    <div class='flex-content'>
      <div class='comment'> Flex Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='flex-element'>
    <div class='flex-content'>
     <div class='comment'> Flex Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```